# 32 bit 14.04 and 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I run 14.04 on my main PC and 12.04 on my old PC ( built 2003 ). My old PC runs OK on 12.04. If I load 14.04 it runs so slow it cannot be used. The main PC is OK using 14.04.

Specs are:

Main PC:

- 3.9gb ram
- Pentium(R) dual core CPU E5300 @ 2.60 GHz x 2
- graphics Gallium 0.4 on NV98
- 32 bit
- Disk 74.4 GB

Old PC:

- 1.5gb ram
- AMD Athlon(tm) XP 1600+
- Graphics unknown
- 32 bit
- Disk 18.0 GB

Any ideas what the problem is and what I should do?

Comment: The graphics on the old computer are very likely the reason it's running slow. Please [edit] to include the output of `lspci | grep VGA` (on the old computer)

Comment: Maybe it's time for an upgrade?